# Authentication for protected routes using express/jwt

Tags: express, get, jwt, middleware, session-storage

When the user logins, the access token is created and sent to the user, it is then stored in sessionStorage. Everything before this works fine. My problem is that I do not know how to use the access token to gain access to protected routes.

express app.js (smoothies is the protected route)

`app.get('/smoothies', requireAuth, (req, res) => res.render('smoothies'));`

authMiddleware.js

```
const User = require('../models/User');

const requireAuth = (req, res, next) => {
  const authHeader = req.headers['authorization']

  const token = authHeader && authHeader.split(' ')[1]
  // check json web token exists & is verified
  if (token) {
    jwt.verify(token, 'night of fire', (err, decodedToken) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err.message);
        res.redirect('/login?err=auth');
      } else {
        console.log(decodedToken);
        next();
      }
    });
  } else {
    res.redirect('/login?err=auth');
  }
};

// check current user

module.exports = { requireAuth };
```

smoothies.ejs

```
  var myHeaders = new Headers();
  myHeaders.append("Authorization", `Bearer ${token}`);

  var requestOptions = {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: myHeaders,
    redirect: 'follow'
  };

  fetch("http://localhost:3000/smoothies", requestOptions)
    .then(response => response.text())
    .then(result => console.log(result))
    .catch(error => console.log('error', error));
//Should I be even doing this fetch GET request on smoothie.ejs? 

 })
```

Smoothies is the protected route. When I try to use Postman and send a GET request to (/smoothies) using authorization : bearer token, it works and I am able to access /smoothies. However, if I try on the real application, I was denied access even with access token in my sessionStorage. When I console.log req.headers['authorization'], it was undefined so I am guessing my GET request from smoothie.ejs does not work. Does anyone know what is the solution?